# what aws permission I should give to acess other s3 buckets

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

In this document (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/install-aws-iam-authenticator.html), tab of `linux`, AWS shared the s3 bucket to download latest version of `aws-iam-authenticator`

this link is keep changing when new version is released, but the bucket name `amazon-eks` is never changed.

```
curl -o aws-iam-authenticator https://amazon-eks.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/1.21.2/2021-07-05/bin/linux/amd64/aws-iam-authenticator
```

without aws API permission you can't detect what are new releases in this folder with programming way, if I directly access via browser: https://amazon-eks.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/1.21.2/2021-07-05/bin/linux

[image]

So I have to use my own AWS Access keys, and it allowed.

```
aws s3 ls s3://amazon-eks/1.21.2/2021-07-05/bin/linux/amd64/
2021-07-15 08:56:11   35290752 aws-iam-authenticator
2021-07-15 08:56:31         55 aws-iam-authenticator.md5
2021-07-15 08:56:31         63 aws-iam-authenticator.sha1
2021-07-15 08:56:31         87 aws-iam-authenticator.sha256
2021-07-15 08:56:31    1865035 cni-amd64-v0.6.0.tgz
2021-07-15 08:56:36         54 cni-amd64-v0.6.0.tgz.md5
2021-07-15 08:56:36         62 cni-amd64-v0.6.0.tgz.sha1
2021-07-15 08:56:36         86 cni-amd64-v0.6.0.tgz.sha256
2021-07-15 08:56:36   36878412 cni-plugins-linux-amd64-v0.8.6.tgz
2021-07-15 08:57:09         68 cni-plugins-linux-amd64-v0.8.6.tgz.md5
2021-07-15 08:57:09         76 cni-plugins-linux-amd64-v0.8.6.tgz.sha1
2021-07-15 08:57:09        100 cni-plugins-linux-amd64-v0.8.6.tgz.sha256
2021-07-15 08:57:09   43122688 kube-proxy
2021-07-15 08:57:43         44 kube-proxy.md5
2021-07-15 08:57:43         52 kube-proxy.sha1
2021-07-15 08:57:43         76 kube-proxy.sha256
2021-07-15 08:57:43   46403584 kubectl
2021-07-15 08:58:23         41 kubectl.md5
2021-07-15 08:58:23         49 kubectl.sha1
2021-07-15 08:58:23         73 kubectl.sha256
2021-07-15 08:58:23  118197040 kubelet
2021-07-15 08:59:44         41 kubelet.md5
2021-07-15 08:59:44         49 kubelet.sha1
2021-07-15 08:59:44         73 kubelet.sha256
```

Now my question is, how can I set an AWS IAM user with `Programmatic access` only, which can't access any resources in my aws account, but allow to list the content in public/private s3 bucket?

I need use this IAM user's access key for a public CICD pipeline build job don't want to take the risk to expose the resources in my own aws account.

#### Update

this is the inline policy for that user

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::amazon-eks/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you want to list the contents of the `amazon-eks` bucket without using credentials.

This can be done by using the `--no-signed-request` option:

```
aws s3 ls s3://amazon-eks/1.21.2/2021-07-05/bin/linux/amd64/ --no-sign-request
```

This avoids the need for providing IAM credentials.

Comment: `--no-sign-request`? that would be the option I am looking for, let me test

Answer (score 0):

I finally figure out the permission with IAM user, but obviously @John Rotenstein's solution is better way.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::amazon-eks/*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::amazon-eks"
        }
    ]
}
```

with above permission, I can list the content in s3 bucket `amazon-eks` without permission to my own aws account.